# Averaging image TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm programming  a function that averages 5 images to extract the background. 'timg' is an array with 5 2D numpy arrays. In those arrays there are stored the images in black and white. imagesize is the size in pixels of the image side(all images are squares)

I've tried changing it to a numpy array and to a python list

```py
def join_images_average(timg,imagesize):
  jimg=timg[0]
  print('averaging')
  for i in range (4):
    print(i+1)
    for x in range(imagesize):
      for y in range(imagesize):
        #print(y)
        jimg[x][y]=jimg[x][y]+timg[i+1][x][y]
        if(jimg[x][y]<0.0):
          jimg[x][y]=0.0
  #plt.imshow(jimg, cmap="gray")
  #plt.show()
  for x in range(imagesize):
      for y in range(imagesize):
        #print(y)
        jimg[x][y]=jimg[x][y]/5
  print(jimg[2])
  jimg=np.array(jimg)
  for i in range(5):
    print(i,jimg[i])
    sleep(5)
    if(i==0):
      a=jimg[i]
    else:
      a=np.sum(a,jimg[i])
  return np.divide(a,5)
```

```
averaging
1
2
3
4
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
0 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
1 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
<ipython-input-38-89e89acc3bc5> in join_images_average(timg, imagesize)
     24       a=jimg[i]
     25     else:
---> 26       a=np.sum(a,jimg[i])
     27   return np.divide(a,5)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial)
   2074 
   2075     return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
-> 2076                           initial=initial)
   2077 
   2078 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     84                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
     85 
---> 86     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
     87 
     88 

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Instead of the explicit loop, sum, and divide, what about `jimg.mean(axis=-1)`?

Comment: The first argument of `np.sum` is an array or list.  The second is the `axis` (may also be given as keyword).  You are passing a list `jimg[i]` as this second parameter.  `np.sum` adds up all the items of the first argument (possibly along one axis).  It is not `a+jimg[i]`.